# want to allow only the post owner to delete

Tags: node.js, spring, backend

If a hacker knows the rest api url and another person's userId, I want to prevent it from being deleted by sending it as a parameter.

I want to store the jwt token in the database and check it before writing. However, after searching, it is said that it is inefficient because it has to be searched every time. Is there any other way?? Short live jwt also exists, but I can't use it either because I have to apply it to the app, not the web. (You can use it, but it's not UX-wise)

If there is another better way, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JWT encodes all the information which the server needs (in so-called *claims*, for example, the user id in the `sub` claim and the expiry time in the `exp` claim). And it contains a signature which the server can validate, and which cannot be forged unless someone has the private key.

The server validates and decodes the token with code like the following:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const signingCertificate = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;
var claims = jwt.verify(token, signingCertificate);
if (claims.exp && claims.exp <= new Date().getTime() / 1000)
  throw "expired";
var user = claims.sub;
```

All this happens on the server, without any token being looked up in a database. And you can then check whether the post to be deleted really belongs to `user`. (This check involves a database access, because you must look up the user to whom the post belongs. But deletion of a post anyway is a database access.)

You don't need a user parameter, because the user is always taken from the token. So even if A knows B's userId and postId, it can only send its own token:

```
POST delete?postId=475
Authorization: Bearer (A's token)
```

and with that it cannot delete B's post 475.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I know that jwt does verify. However, all app users can verify. (Everyone has their own jwt token. In Shared Preference or locally on the smartphone) But if A knows B's userId, send B's ID to the parameter and send its own jtw token (A's token), A can edit B's post? // Both A's token and B's token will verify successfully, how do I identify the uniqueness of each?

Comment: There is no security gap, see my augmented answer.

Comment: Hi, to clarify, in this case I need a database lookup, right? (Checking whether the token of the user of the post and the token received through the server request are correct) answer me, so I can adopt your answer

Comment: You need a database lookup, but only for the relation between the post to be deleted and its author. No database lookup is needed for the token validation.